# Сайты с открытым счетчиком яндекс метрики

Tags: c#, yandex-metrika-api

Добрый день, делаю небольшое приложение которое использует API яндекс метрики, для тестирования мне нужен номер счетчика с публичным доступом, однако я не смог пока найти такой, может кто подсказать где можно его найти?

Comment: Это как бы не совсем вопрос по программированию. А почему бы вам самому не сделать такой сайт для тестов?

Comment: Извиняюсь если вопрос не по теме, просто я никогда созданием сайтов не занимался, и думал что проще узнать есть ли доступные существующие метрики, чем делать самому сайт и устанавливать счетчик.

Comment: Понимаю. С такими вопросами лучше по идее в чат, но у вас как на зло репутация только 1 покамест, так что чат не пустит. Там надо-то всего 40, это два ответа примерно